# typed array speed vs normal variables

Tags: javascript, performance, typed-arrays

I've been comparing typed array speed with normal variables and I was expecting to see typed array to be faster than normal variables but instead it is the opposite. Here my test:

```
function typedarraytest (iterations) {
    var vb8 = new Uint8Array(16);
    var vb32 = new Uint32Array(vb8);
    for (vb32[0] = 0; vb32[0] < iterations; vb32[0]++) {
        for (vb32[1] = 0; vb32[1] < iterations; vb32[1]++) {
            for (vb32[2] = 0; vb32[2] < iterations; vb32[2]++) {
                vb32[3] = vb32[0] + vb32[1] + vb32[2];
            }
        }
    };   
}
function normaltest (iterations) {
    var A, B, C, D;
    for (A = 0; A < iterations; A++) {
        for (B = 0; B < iterations; B++) {
            for (C = 0; C < iterations; C++) {
                D = A + B + C;
            }
        }
    };
}
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var timeStart = new Date();
    typedarraytest (500);
    var timeFinish = new Date();
    console.log("TA: " + (timeFinish - timeStart));
    var timeStart = new Date();
    normaltest (500);
    var timeFinish = new Date();
    console.log("NT: " + (timeFinish - timeStart));
}
```

Here the results I get from the console:

```
TA: 332
NT: 128
TA: 312
NT: 83
TA: 324
NT: 80
TA: 313
NT: 81
TA: 316
NT: 82
TA: 325
NT: 79
TA: 317
NT: 80
TA: 312
NT: 78
TA: 318
NT: 80
TA: 319
NT: 81
```

Are there fast typed variables that I can use?

Comment: Typed arrays are typed **arrays**, not typed variables. You should use them only when you need a (large) structure, and compare them to normal `Array`s at best. Creating an object structure will always be slower than not creating it.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I noticed that removing the "var" declarations and moving them to "this" makes the variable as slow as they typed array. That is really interesting. Since I need anyway the class variables since I need multiple instances, I will still use TypedArrays since they give me some advantages.